# Could not connect to FreeNX server using Desktop--->Shadow

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, freenx

I have installed FreeNX server on ubuntu 10.04 Desktop and I could connect to the system remotely with NXClient selecting "UNIX" and "GNOME". I want to use the 'shadow' feature of NX and I could not able to connect to this FreeNX computer using "Shadow" and below shows the 'Details' of the error the nxclient shows:

```
NX> 203 NXSSH running with pid: 1472

NX> 285 Enabling check on switch command

NX> 285 Enabling skip of SSH config files

NX> 285 Setting the preferred NX options

NX> 200 Connected to address: <my-public-ip-here> on port: 22

NX> 202 Authenticating user: nx

NX> 208 Using auth method: publickey

HELLO NXSERVER - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.4.0)

NX> 105 hello NXCLIENT - Version 3.2.0

NX> 134 Accepted protocol: 3.2.0

NX> 105 SET SHELL_MODE SHELL

NX> 105 SET AUTH_MODE PASSWORD

NX> 105 login

NX> 101 User: user1

NX> 102 Password: 

NX> 103 Welcome to: ubuntu-desktop user: user1

NX> 105 listsession --type="shadow"

NX> 127 Sessions list of user '.*' for reconnect:



Display Type             Session ID                       Options  Depth Screen         Status      Session Name

------- ---------------- -------------------------------- -------- ----- -------------- ----------- ------------------------------

0       Local            511F1EC3F84D9E4966D69BD8C4A33524 --------                      Running     X0 (Local)

0       Local            5B89B05C835121F9431AB6AEAD0E53B2 --------                      Running     X0 (Local)





NX> 148 Server capacity: not reached for user: .*

NX> 105 listsession --type="shadow"

NX> 127 Sessions list of user '.*' for reconnect:



Display Type             Session ID                       Options  Depth Screen         Status      Session Name

------- ---------------- -------------------------------- -------- ----- -------------- ----------- ------------------------------

0       Local            511F1EC3F84D9E4966D69BD8C4A33524 --------                      Running     X0 (Local)

0       Local            5B89B05C835121F9431AB6AEAD0E53B2 --------                      Running     X0 (Local)





NX> 148 Server capacity: not reached for user: .*

NX> 105 attachsession  --link="modem" --backingstore="1" --encryption="1" --cache="16M" --images="64M" --shmem="1" --shpix="1" --strict="0" --composite="1" --media="0" --session="ubuntu" --type="shadow" --client="winnt" --keyboard="pc105/en_US" --id="5B89B05C835121F9431AB6AEAD0E53B2" --display="0"



NX> 596 Could not find shadowed session 5B89B05C835121F9431AB6AEAD0E53B2. Session failed.

NX> 596 Sharing: 

NX> 105 NX> 280 Exiting on signal: 15
```

Anybody could help instructing in right direction?